# `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)

Tags: jekyll

I was following up from https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/ to install Jekyll and I have made sure that I have `Xcode command line tools, gcc and make` installed. Version of ruby is 2.1.1  I have installed Jekyll using

```
gem install jekyll
```

I got following success message

```
  Done installing documentation for safe_yaml, rouge, forwardable-extended, pathutil, mercenary, liquid, kramdown, ffi, rb-inotify, rb-fsevent, listen, jekyll-watch, sass-listen, sass, jekyll-sass-converter, colorator, public_suffix, addressable, jekyll after 14 seconds
        19 gems installed
```

But when I execute `jekyll --version`

I got following error

```
/Users/amar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /Users/amar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/amar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:46:in `require_from_bundler'
    from /Users/amar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/exe/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/amar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /Users/amar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/amar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/amar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error was solved by installing new version of bundler again, I had installed it previously as well but there was version issue

```
gem install bundler
```

Check your bundler version by

```
bundler --version
```

If everything is fine it will show version #
Then again run `jekyll --version` and everything should go fine